# Access to a service or feature has been restricted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I received an email from ts-consult@google.com, requesting me to "Make a payment (https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6294016?hl=en) of $100 from the Transaction History page (https://console.developers.google.com/billing) and reply to this message when the charge clears." However, I am currently unable to access "https://console.developers.google.com/billing" as it shows "Access to a service or feature has been restricted." What should I do?

I added $100 on the exchange rate to my Google Cloud account under Subscriptions and Services in Google Payments Center to cover future charges.
please allow me to have the authority of the billing console, otherwise I cannot make the payment.